Manga where the female lead is transported to another world where people’s heads are non-human
FL has trauma from being abused by her boyfriend/husband in her world. ML has a full-metal mask/helmet type of head, and his friend has a bear head. ML helps her when she’s transported to his world and adopts her as a pet (something they do with otherworlders). She’s attached to him because of his kindness, but she can’t speak due to her trauma.
Later on, she relearns how to use her voice to speak to him. She gets medical help from a human female doctor who’s also originally from her world. The female doctor and the ML’s friend with the bear head are the second couple.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Igyou Atama-san to Ningen-chan or The Aberrant-Headed Guy and the Human Girl

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please [edit] your answer to add more details on how this work answers the question. You can find tips on how to write a good identification answer and what details to add in our guide.
